# Sorting a matrix by the minimum values by rows

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have some matrixes and operations and I end up with one matrix called "MatrizFinal", which has a number and then an id that goes from 0 to n in order. I want to sort the matrix so the rows are ordered by the minimum value of the numbers (NOT THE ID) (because I will take the minimum values later on so I need the id.

```
 import numpy as np

v1=np.matrix('1,2;3,4;2,6;4,5')
v2=np.matrix('5,6;7,8;1,2;3,4')
print('first matrix')
print(v1)
print('second matrix:')
print(v2)

k=0

distancias = []
posiciones=[]

#do the euclidean distance and also add the position from 0 to n, depending on the rows it has.
for i in v1:

    distancias.append(np.linalg.norm(v2-v1[k,:]))
    posiciones.append(k)
    print(distancias[k])
    k=k+1

print(distancias)
print (posiciones)
#create a matrix that has both columns
matrizFinal=np.column_stack((distancias, posiciones))
print (matrizFinal)
```

The output final matrix is:

```
 [[ 10.58300524   0.        ]
 [  6.92820323   1.        ]
 [  7.74596669   2.        ]
 [  6.32455532   3.        ]]
```

But I want to order rows from the minimum value to the max value. In this example, the result I want is:

```
 [[ 6.32455532   3.        ]
 [  6.92820323   1.        ]
 [  7.74596669   2.        ]
 [  10.58300524   0.       ]]
```

But the numpy sorting algorithms don't work. How can I do it?

Comment: Flip by rows : `matrizFinal[::-1]`?

Comment: If `numpy` doesn't do it for you, use base Python.  Convert to a list of lists, sort those, and convert back to an array.

Comment: That only works in this example. I need to sort it by the minimum value in case i have, for example, 10 rows, with different values NOT ordered by maximum or minimum. So that does not work. @Divakar

Comment: But if I sort the list of lists, I will then lose the id "attached" to the number value, which I do not want. I want to have the values ordereded by minimum and then know which id it has. I also do not know if numpy cannot do it. I have tried several sorting numpy algorithms and they do not work.

Comment: `matrizFinal[matrizFinal[:,0].argsort()[::-1]]`? Not tested tho.

Comment: Not working :( @Divakar

Comment: Could you present a bit more larger MCVE? Two elems aren't enough data to verify. Also, any good reason for using `np.matrix` and not `np.array`?

Comment: I am going to edit my question so I have 4 rows instead of 2. It will be more visible. 
Also, I am using `np.matrix`  because I need to combine those 2 matrixes after the operation with `np.column_stack`. And I am not really sure if I can do that with `np.array`

Comment: Skip the flipping, so : `matrizFinal[matrizFinal[:,0].argsort()]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works fine! @Divakar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have tested it, it works fine in Python 3.6.1

```
M = np.matrix(sorted(matrizFinal, key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

I'm pretty sure there are better (and faster) ways to do it, but this is the first one that comes to my mind.

Suerte!

Edit: Sorry I didn't understand your question, but the 4x4 matrix helped me. Now I think it does what you expected.

Comment: I was going to say: "I've tried it and it orders it by the ID, not by the values!" but thanks to your edit it works fine now!  Lots of thanks! Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues using numpy sort as you mentioned in your question, where each column would not be sorted with respects to the other columns. To overcome this we can find the indices of the column you want to sort and then apply to all columns.

A numpy solution:

```
>>> matrizFinal[np.argsort(matrizFinal, axis=0)[:,0]]
>>> array([[  6.32455532 ,   3.  ],
   [  6.92820323 ,   1.  ],
   [  7.74596669 ,   2.  ],
   [ 10.58300524 ,   0.  ]])
```

where [:,0] extracts the indices from column 0.